# PySpark, order of column on write to MySQL with JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling a bit understanding spark and writing dataframes to a mysql database. I have the following code:

```
forecastDict = {'uuid': u'8df34d5a-ce02-4d02-b282-e10363690122', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 23, 0)}
forecastFrame =  sqlContext.createDataFrame([forecastDict])    
forecastFrame.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://example.com/example_db?user=bla&password=blabal123", table="example_table", mode="append")
```

The last line in the code throws the following error:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '8df34d5a-ce02-4d02-b282-e10363690122' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

I can post the entire stack trace if necessary, but basically what's happening here is that the `pyspark` is mapping the `uuid` field to the wrong column in mysql. Here's the mysql definition:

```
mysql> show create table example_table;
...
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
`uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
...
```

If we change the mysql definition to the following (**notice that only the order of the columns is different**):

```
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The insert works fine. Is there a way to implement this without being dependent on the order of the columns, or what's the preferred way of saving data to an external relational database from spark?

Thanks!

--chris

Answer (score 5):

I would simply force expected order on write:

```
url = ...
table = ...

columns = (sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')
  .options(url=url, dbtable=table)
  .load()
  .columns())

forecastFrame.select(*columns).write.jdbc(url=url, dbtable=table, mode='append')
```

Also be careful with using schema inference on dictionaries. This is not only deprecated but also rather unstable.